# NServiceBus - How to configure bus to allow WindowsIdentity to flow from client

Tags: c#, nservicebus, windows-identity

On the client I have setup the bus with `ImpersonateSender(true)`

My server is configured `AsA_Server`, which by default should have `ImpersonateSender(true)`

I'm now trying to retrieve the WindowsIdentity, from inside a Handler

```
var windowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(true);
```

But this is giving me null.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Use System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal instead.

Also, don't set ImpersonateSender on the client - it'll send it's credentials regardless.

Comment: I looked at that, but that only gives me a GenericPrincipal. I need to get WindowsIdentity so I can get the windows token for the user.

Comment: Tackling the problem in a different way:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854198/nservicebus-how-to-pass-custom-headers-in-the-message-envelop

Comment: Inside the CurrentPrincipal is an IIdentity which can be cast to a WindowsIdentity.

Comment: Hi I have one question here. How to execute the stored message on certain windowsIdentity. Is there any way to recreate the windowsidentity.currentprincipal from incoming message header ? Because when I crash Saga and re-run then the incoming messages are getting executed in my windows credential. Which is wrong , it was supposed to run on the original context which

Comment: I tried even from MVC webproject i am getting windows identity correct. However when it goes to End point then Thread.CurrentPrincipal is different it takes from my windowsNT id. NSErvicebus is not passing the exact CurrentPrincipal which is there in MVC web project. Request.LogonUserIdentity . Is there anyway to pass exact logonUserIdentity to Endpoint ?

Comment: I have another thread  for my issue related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736912/how-to-impersonate-nservicebus