# NServiceBus - How to pass custom headers in the Message envelop?

Tags: c#, header, nservicebus

I want to be able to attach the windows authentication token without having to include that piece of data on the messages themselves.

I've noticed that TransportMessage has Headers, but how do I get access to that before Send message to server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the [Header Manipulation Sample](http://docs.particular.net/samples/header-manipulation/) there you'll see how to use headers.

To set a constant outgoing header for a client (suitable for the auth token you want), see [Writing outgoing headers for all outgoing-messages](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/header-manipulation#writing-outgoing-headers-for-all-outgoing-messages)

On the server, you can then [Read the header](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/header-manipulation#reading-incoming-headers).