# How to impersonate Nservicebus

Tags: nservicebus

Hi How to impersonate Nservicebus. I am using Nservicebus 5.2 version.

I see some code for old version but that is not available in new version.
Do we have some sample which demonstrate the impersonate in 5.2 version.

```
 Configure.With()
        .StructureMapBuilder()
        .Sagas()
        .RunTimeoutManager()
        .UnicastBus()
           .ImpersonateSender(false)
```

In New version there is no way to set

> ImpersonateSender

Does anyone know how to pass the exact currentprincipal object up to END points?

I tried to start my endpoint by below command line.
`Start NServiceBus.Host.exe /displayName:"myservice" /username:"mydomain\myname"   /password:"mypwd"`

However when I log userName then it is not picking the same username which I used to start endpoint.

```
  public void Customize(BusConfiguration configuration)
        {


            configuration.UsePersistence<RavenDBPersistence>()

            Console.WriteLine("-------------------NAME--------------\n");
            Console.WriteLine(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------NAME--------------\n");


            Console.WriteLine("-------------------NAME--------------\n");
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------NAME--------------\n");
        }
```

output comes like:
-------------------NAME--------------

MYNetworkDomain\MyMachineLoggedInNTId
-------------------NAME--------------

-------------------NAME--------------

-------------------NAME--------------

Comment: I want to run one call with windows impersonation. I can set the claims, windows credentials stuff in the header of all outgoing message. Then is it possible to fetch it and from incoming message and set the Thread.CurrentPrincipal

Comment: How to execute the stored message on certain windowsIdentity. Is there any way to recreate the windowsidentity.currentprincipal from incoming message header ? My Scenario: First time when I run Saga with windowsauthentication enabled it asks me my credential, I put some different credential (different domain\user) which is not my windows NT id. Then Saga sends command End point executes on the same credential when I do identity.impersonate. However, in situation when Saga is crashed and I rerun the project then all messages goes to endpoint and that is running with my windowsNTId and failing.

Comment: I Tried to run that END point with below command line but still while debugging the code it is taking my machines NT id credentials.   `Start NServiceBus.Host.exe /displayName:"MyEndpoint" /username:"MYDomain\MyUserName" /password:"MyPassword"`

Comment: One update: When I right click on host.exe and run it as different user pass my needful credentials then it goes into CurrentPrincipal. and It works.

Answer (score 0):

Impersonation in .Net can have many flavors and may not end up behaving as you might expect.
In v4 when `.ImpersonateSender(...)` was set to true the behavior was to deliver along with the message, using a message header, the identity name used at the sender endpoint, the recipient would have used the incoming message header to set up a new `generic identity`.

It is not a real impersonation, not to mention that impersonation to work across different machines requires delegation to be set up, with all the security concerns that delegation brings to the table. Not to mention that, AFAIK, Windows Identity impersonation can't be done at the thread level, the security token is attached to the process and can't be overwritten by a thread pretending to be a different user.

That said, nothing prevents you to build your own logic to deliver identities along with messages in order to have .Net identity/principal infrastructure setup as you like and be able to perform security checks via the `Role` infrastructure.